C# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Index out of range setting HeaderText in Designer file
I have a DataGridView on a form which has a ComboBox column in it.
There is no data source for the grid when the form loads as it gets loaded to the grid by another method triggered by the user.
When the form loads (instance of a form is created), I am getting the error:
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
I have narrowed it down to the line in the form's Designer file when the Header Text is set for the column. This is the line of code causing the error in the Form1.Designer.cs file:
this.gridComboBox1.HeaderText = "Options";

If I comment out this line, the form loads without issue, but the header of the combobox column in the grid is then just "gridComboBox1", which is obviously not ideal.
I am using Visual Studio to create my forms, so tried just adding a brand new datagridview control to the app from the toolbox and setting up the columns without changing any settings other than setting the column type and header text. But I get the same issue, which makes me think this is an issue with winforms generally as it's offering functionality that doesn't work.
I also get the same error if I try and programmatically change the header text in the Form's Load event.
I'm still pretty new to C# and have been unable to figure out why this is happening. The column itself is added earlier on in the code in the designer file like this:
this.dgv1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.select,
            this.gridComboBox1,
            this.DataType});

So the column should be there for the later code to interact with.
Is anybody able to shed some light on why this would be as it makes no sense to me.

You should not manually edit xxx.Designer.cs files, they are meant to be generated by winforms designer and error is likely due to some manual edit. Revert changes (if you don't use source control yet, start using one) or create a new form.

Hi @Sinatr The only edit I made to the Designer file was to comment out the line of code that tries to set the header text because this is the line of code causing the error.  It doesn't explain why the winforms designer cannot set the header text and instead throws the error. Even after clicking OK to the error the form still loads ok. This is the only issue with the form, the grid performs exactly as I need it.

Please refer to [mcve]. If you post a complete error containing stack trace, someone may try to guess what's going wrong in the code you didn't show. The designer generated code you show is unlikely to be a reason.

"tried just adding a new grid control to the app from the toolbox and setting up the columns, but I get the same issue" - make new app, reproduce the issue, post code and steps.

@Sinatr see my new post. I believe I have fixed the issue

I've done some more investigation now, and I believe I have fixed the issue.
I am subscribing to the CellValueChanged event to trigger some code which populates another column in the grid depending on the option selected from the ComboBox column.
However, this event is getting triggered when the header text is being set by the designer code.
This is the code in question:
private void dgv1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) // index of the combobox column
        {
            string mappedField = dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
            string sql = @$"SELECT 
                            UPPER(DATA_TYPE) 
                            + CASE 
                                WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('nvarchar', 'varchar') AND CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN '(MAX)' 
                                WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('nvarchar', 'varchar') THEN '('+CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')' 
                                ELSE '' 
                                END AS DATA_TYPE 
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Report'
                        AND COLUMN_NAME = '{mappedField}';";
            string targetDataType = clsRepeatableMethods.SQLOutputToStringVariable(sql, clsConnections.ConnStrStg);

            dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["RepDataType"].Value = targetDataType;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

Because there are no rows in the grid other than the header row when the grid is created by the designer, the index out of range error is returned.
The fix was to put a check in for the row index also.
I changed this line of code:
if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)

To this:
if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex == 1)

Now it's all working. As I said previously, I'm new to C# and didn't think that the CellValueChanged event would get triggered by a change to the header row.
Thanks to @Sinatr who's comments led me to look further afield at what other code could be triggered.

The debugger in Visual Studio should stop at problematic line with invalid index during run-time in debug-session. Add a design-time check for the code which is not intended to execute in winforms deisgner.
